# Zend controller extends from two class

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, zend-controller

In my application I have got a main controller in which I have a few methods. One of them checks if the user is logged in and if not it redirects the user to login form etc.

```
class FA_Controller_Auth extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  public function preDispatch() {
   //chceck user is login
  }
}
```

aand all controllers extend from this main class

```
IndexController extends FA_Controller_Auth{}
```

but now I am building multi payment gatwey from Zend_Payment_Controllerso Payment_GatewayController should extend from Zend_Payment_Controller. But I need to chack if the user is logged in or not and I am looking for somthing like multi extend

```
Payment_GatewayController extends Zend_Payment_Controller, FA_Controller_Auth
```

I know there is no way to use multi extend class in PHP but maybe there is a better way to do this, action helper or plugin to check authorisation ?
Regards.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only extend one class. This is exactly why using a base controller class is considered bad practice, as it limits you somewhat. Instead you should move the logic for both checks into controller plugins instead.

Comment: thanks a lot that was very useful! But controller plugin is run to every controller and action but some action doesn't need to be checked for authorization so I have to do it is disabled authorisation check for this action:
`class SilverCms_Controller_Plugin_Auth extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $oRequest)
    {
        $sAction = strtolower($oRequest->getActionName());
if($sAction === 'confirmEmail'){
            return;
}}`
maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Nope, how you're doing it is the best way.